# Roots of two fundamental solutions in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ are the fundamental solutions of the differential equation below:

$y''(x)+p(x)y'(x)+q(x)y=0$

Where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are continuous functions.

Prove that between two continuous roots of $y_{1}$ there is only one root of $y_{2}$.

I know that when it says that the solutions are fundamental, it means that their wronskian isn't zero. But it doesn't help in proving what it asks.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Show that the angle of the point $(y_1(t),y_2(t))$ only ever moves in one direction.

Comment: @lutzlehmann can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Take the angle arctan formula and compute its derivative. Compare with the Wronskian. Also see the duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679480/roots-of-linearly-independent-solutions-of-homogeneous-ode-2, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223407/proof-involving-wronski-determinant